# iframe allowed only to my app (Intel XDK)

Tags: iframe, webview, intel-xdk

I am using Intel XDK iframe to convert my website to an app. I want that only my app can show my website at an iframe. How can i do it?
To prevent others to use my web at an iframe i have this code at my web to prevent iframe, but with this code my app can't iframe my web:

```
if(top.location!=this.location) top.location=this.location
```

Any way to allow only my app to iframe my web?

Answer (score 0):

Your application runs the risk of rejection by using an iframe according Section 4.2 of the review guidelines

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#design

4.2 Minimum Functionality

Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it beyond a repackaged website.

If your website is based on WordPress, you can use the Quickapp to generate an Android APK file for distribution for the PlayStore, no support for IPA with the AppStore. (https://wordpress.org/plugins/quickapp)

Apple is very picky in their App review which explains the review process taking two weeks on average.

The Intel XDK used HTML5, CSS and JavaScript with Cordova/Node for app development, most sites can be converted to a mobile equivalent. My suggestion is to include an extra feature in your mobile app that is not available from the website.